# Hide one line in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I have one line in a html file containing a base64 representation of an image. This line spans thousands of lines in the editor, which is a huge hassle when always scrolling past it.

Is there a good way in ST3 of hiding this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the text you want to hide, then from the Edit menu -> Code Folding -> Fold.

Note that folding is not stored in the session, and reopening the file or ST will display the text unfolded again.

You could also take a look at plugins designed to help you with this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Base64%20Fold

Answer (score 0):

you can simply press ctrl+shift+{ and to revert back just press ctrl+shift+}